# problems typing PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I need help, I've searched all over Google and can't find any info...
When entering a command

```
Get-adobject -filter * -properties *
```

I get an error:

```
Get-ADObject : Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
```

But if you replace `-properties *` with:

```
-Properties CanonicalName, CN, Created, Deleted, Description, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, LastKnownParent, Modified, Name, ObjectCategory, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion
```

... then everything works.

Comment: What do you mean with "if you display all the parameters separately" - what _exact_ commands are you running when it works?

Comment: if replace -properties * with -Properties CanonicalName, CN, Created, Deleted, Description, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, LastKnownParent, Modified, Name, ObjectCategory, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion

Comment: That means that at least 1 object in the directory has at least 1 attribute that contains a timestamp value that `DateTime` considers invalid (like "30th of february", or the year `-1`). To find the object in question, retrieve all objects without `-Properties *`, then query each of those individually for all properties - once you receive the same error, you'll know which account has an invalid timestamp

Comment: I tried to test on one account, with the properties * parameter it gives an error, but when displaying all the parameters separately, it displays normally, that is, for one user different errors depending on the application of the properties parameter

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the error you receive means that at least 1 object in the directory has at least 1 attribute that contains a timestamp value that the `[DateTime]` type considers invalid (like "30th of february", or the year -1).

To find the object(s) in question:

- Retrieve all objects (without specifying `-Properties *`), then
- Query each of those individually for all properties - once you
  receive the same error, you'll know which account has an invalid
  timestamp, and you can then

  - Query the schema for all timestamp-valued attributes
  - Fetch only that specific additional property on each query until the error occurs

Let's start by retrieving all objects and find one that's affected by `-Properties *`:

```
foreach($object in Get-ADObject -Filter *){
    try {
        $object |Get-ADObject -Properties * -ErrorAction Stop |Out-Null
    } catch {
        "Found affected object: $($object.DistinguishedName)"
        $affected = $object
        break
    }
}
```

Now that you can discover an affected object, we need to identify the specific attribute that has the invalid value. To do so, query the schema for all attributes that are stored as timestamps:

```
$timestampAttributeSchemas = Get-ADObject -Filter "objectClass -eq 'attributeSchema' -and attributeSyntax -eq '2.5.5.11'" -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -Properties LDAPDisplayName
```

And then query the directory for only one of those additional properties at a time:

```
foreach($attribute in $timestampAttributeSchemas){
    try {
        $affected |Get-ADObject -Properties $attribute.LDAPDisplayName -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        "Attribute $($attribute.LDAPDisplayName) appears to be affected"
    }
}
```